# MissingHelperError - New rails install

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I just installed ROR on my windows machine. I created a project but when I run `rails s` i get an application_helper.rb error

this is the exact error I am getting.

```
AbstractController::Helpers::MissingHelperError in Rails::WelcomeController#index
```

I have tried changing the directory, running bundle install and several other little things but nothing seems to be making a difference.

Comment: did you run bundle install?

Comment: yup, sure did and nothing changes